# Grouping items in a list using python defaultdic

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a list called "GO_file":

```
GO_file = ["A_1 12", "A_2 13", "A_3 14", "A_4 12", "B_1 1", "B_2 1", "B_3 5"]
```

I want to convert it to:

A: 12, 13, 14

B: 1, 5

```
from collections import defaultdict
GO_file = ["A_1 12", "A_2 13", "A_3 14", "A_4 12", "B_1 1", "B_2 1" "B_3 5"]

GO_dict = defaultdict(list)
for GO_names in GO_file:
   gene_id = GO_names.split("_")[0]
   GO_id = GO_names.split(" ")[1:]
   GO_dict[gene_id] = GO_id
print GO_dict
```

However, this code only append key and only one value:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['12'], 'B': ['5']})
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has few issues

1. There are duplicates in your GO_ID, and you seem to only care about unique. So you need a `defaultdict(set)` instead of `defaultdict(list)`
2. Your split algorithm to generate the key and value is buggy
3. `GO_dict[gene_id] = GO_id`, simply assigns the last value to the dict instead of appending it.

A possible corrected solution

```
>>> GO_dict = defaultdict(set)
>>> for GO_names in GO_file:
   gene_id,_,GO_id = GO_names.partition(" ")
   gene_id = gene_id.split("_")[0]
   GO_dict[gene_id].add(GO_id)


>>> print GO_dict
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'A': set(['13', '12', '14']), 'B': set(['1', '5'])})
```

One possible problem with the above code is, the order of the elements are not guaranteed. Unfortunately the default library does not provide an `OrderedSet`, but we can easily customize `OrderedDict` to server our purpose

```
>>> GO_dict = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
>>> for GO_names in GO_file:
   gene_id,_,GO_id = GO_names.partition(" ")
   gene_id = gene_id.split("_")[0]
   GO_dict[gene_id][GO_id] = None


>>> OrderedDict([('A', ['12', '13', '14']), ('B', ['1', '5'])])
OrderedDict([('A', ['12', '13', '14']), ('B', ['1', '5'])])
```

**But**

There are cases, as this one I believe, where the `itertools` solution is more elegant than using `defaultdict`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> GO_file_kv = [(key.split("_")[0], value) 
                   for key, value in (elem.split(" ") for elem in GO_file)]
>>> {key: OrderedDict.fromkeys([e for _, e in value]).keys()
     for key, value in groupby(sorted(GO_file_kv, key=itemgetter(0)),
                       key=itemgetter(0))
 }
{'A': ['12', '13', '14'], 'B': ['1', '5']}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit for the comprehensive answer!